# How does a program communicate with the X11 Server on Linux?

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, dbus

So I made quite a lot of research about this and couldn't find the answer.

Does it use a named pipe ? a socket on localhost ? d-bus ?

Can I intercept and see the binary messages sent by an X client to the X server with a line of bash ?

Of course this is only for educational purpose. I don't intend to build a software that would intercept such messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses a Unix domain socket, of the name `/tmp/.X11-unix/X${DISPLAYNUMBER}`. These days Linux support a special naming for Unix domain sockets, called "abstract namespace UDS", where the path is prepended with an `@`, but is otherwise the same.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other answer, there is also TCP/IP. In fact, a program can use an X11 server running on a totally different machine, even traveling the world.

You can use for example:

```
DISPLAY=192.168.1.56:0 xterm
```

and the program xterm(1) will connect to the machine indicated by $DISPLAY using a TCP/IP connection.